# How do I improve debugging of an 'Expected BEGIN-OBJECT but was string' error in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: json, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I am currently working on a project using a layered architecture with Blazor WebAssembly and I am encountering a problem related to a malformed Json result.  The issue concerns the following error when calling a function to render a table fragment with MudBlazor.  The error is 'Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was string at line 1 Column 356' which I have isolated to a service call using the debugger. It is at the point where the JSON is being converted into a List using GetFromJsonAsync. What is puzzling is that in Swagger the controller does produce a valid JSON result!  I've even copied and pasted this data into a JSON file where I am not seeing any formatting issues.  Unfortunately due to where I work, I am not able to post code or sample data.

As for the development environment, I am using Entity Framework where I am seeding sample data which has been loaded into my local SQL Server.  Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Or does anyone have any recommendations in how to isolate this problem further?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried Try Catch to capture a JsonException but nothing is logging.

Comment: Please show sample json and the class structure.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, I simply cannot provide code or data due to what I work on.

Comment: The provide a [mre] representing the issue.

Comment: Hi, guru. I was able to answer my own question.  My problem was putting too much trust in the GetFromJsonFromAsync function.  Although its optimized, it doesn't throw a conversion error which is what I was able to finally determine. I posted a sample model that I used  as a reference pattern

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delete this post I wanted to provide an aid that should give more information to developers that experience that same problem.  Simply put, I recommend NOT using GetFromJsonAsync rather I am using a pattern as shown below.  This will provide a lot more information to the developer.

```
        using System;
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Net.Json;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
        
        
        public class MyService
        {
            private readonly Ilogger<MyService> _logger;
            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
            
            public MyService(Ilogger<MyService> logger, HttpClient httpClient){
                _logger = logger;
                _httpClient = httpClient;
            }
            
            public async Task MyMethod()
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpReponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://example.com")
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MyData>
                    
                    //process data
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the response."
                    //handle the error.
                }
            }
            
        }
```